# Taxonomy nav for levels 1 through 3, while current page is level 4?

Tags: navigation, taxonomy

My multi-level menu works fine for pages at levels 1, 2 and 3.

```
{exp:taxonomy:nav 
 tree_id="1" 
 display_root="no" 
 active_branch_start_level="1" 
 depth="3"
    {if {embed:entry_id} }
        entry_id="{embed:entry_id}"
    {/if}
    {if {embed:node_id} }
        node_id="{embed:node_id}"
    {/if}
 }
```

However, when I reach a URL at level 4, the menu disappears. This is to be expected, because of the depth="3" parameter. If I change it to "4", then my menu expands to show all four levels, but that's not what I want. I want the menu to show only three levels, even if the current URL is in level 4.

How can I show the same 3-level menu at all times, even when I'm on a level 4 page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass an `entry_id` or `node_id` parameter, Taxonomy is looking for that active node in the tree and assigns all the appropriate vars like `{active}`, `{active_parent}` etc. If the active node is not found in the tree, Taxonomy will not output the nav.

As you're asking for a subset of the tree, flagging that you want an active branch subset, and supplying the active node which doesn't exist in that subset; Taxonomy is not rendering anything.

So, remove the depth param, and wrap the `{children}` variable in a conditonal, for example:

```
{exp:taxonomy:nav 
    entry_id="{entry_id}"
    tree_id="1" 
    display_root="no" 
    active_branch_start_level="1" 
}
    <li><a href="{node_url}">{node_title}</a>{if node_level < 3}{children}{/if}</li>
{/exp:taxonomy:nav}
```

There are a few other ways of doing it, but this would be the most straight forward. Let me know if you're still not getting the results you need.